# how can I draw a round diagonal corners in flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, drawing, shapes

how can I draw a round diagonal corners in flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderRadius/BorderRadius.only.html in the box decoration of a container widget.